# Unique randomly select numbers in a array

Tags: matlab, random

If I have 10 numbers in an array `a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`
How can I make 5 sets of randomly select two numbers in each set and the numbers should be unique in all 5 sets?

For the above array, the answer should be:

```
S1=[3 8]
S2=[2 5]
S3=[1 4]
S4=[6 9]
S5=[7 10]
```

Comment: Can you please fix the wording of the post to clarify what you actually mean? An example of a possibly valid result might help.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You can use [randperm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [randperm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to generate a random index into the original vector, and use it to shuffle the original vector.  Then, just take the elements of the shuffled vector in order:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
shuffled = a(randperm(length(a)));
sets = reshape(shuffled,5,2);
```

Your variables `S1` through `S5` correspond to each row of the matrix `sets`.